# GetAsyncKeyState do not work when multiple keys are pressed

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++

I have a problem with getting keyboard state using `GetAsyncKeyState` function (I've tried using `GetKeyboardState` function, but result is the same).

I need to implement the following functionality: on each frame application  should process all available Windows messages, execute frame update routine, and frame render routine. For the update part I need to get keyboard state at the moment of the update (that is why I'm using `GetAsyncKeyState` instead of `GetKeyState`).

I've written a sample code that demonstrates the behavior I get. It sets a list of pressed keys into window's title. For simplicity it processes only alpha keys.

Use case example: Press A key and do not release it, then press B, and after that C. It should be "A, B, C, " in the title now. If you'll press D key it should appear as "A, B, C, D, ", but it's not. You can try different key combinations. Sometimes it shows 5, 6, or even more keys that are pressed.

So I have two questions:

1. Why do I get this behavior?
2. How can I achieve the desired behavior? (Get state of all keys, preferably using WinAPI.)

P.S. Environment: MSVS 2015 Enterprise, Windows 10 Pro.

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void Render(HWND window, wstring keyboardState)
{
    SetWindowText(window, keyboardState.c_str());
}

void UpdateKeyState(int key, wstring& keyboardState)
{
    if ((GetAsyncKeyState(key) & 0x8000) != 0)
    {
        keyboardState.append(1, key);
        keyboardState.append(L", ");
    }
}

void Update(wstring& keyboardState)
{
    keyboardState.clear();

    UpdateKeyState('A', keyboardState);
    UpdateKeyState('B', keyboardState);
    UpdateKeyState('C', keyboardState);
    UpdateKeyState('D', keyboardState);
    UpdateKeyState('E', keyboardState);
    UpdateKeyState('F', keyboardState);
    UpdateKeyState('G', keyboardState);
    UpdateKeyState('H', keyboardState);
    UpdateKeyState('I', keyboardState);
    UpdateKeyState('J', keyboardState);
    UpdateKeyState('K', keyboardState);
    UpdateKeyState('L', keyboardState);
    UpdateKeyState('M', keyboardState);
    UpdateKeyState('N', keyboardState);
    UpdateKeyState('O', keyboardState);
    UpdateKeyState('P', keyboardState);
    UpdateKeyState('Q', keyboardState);
    UpdateKeyState('R', keyboardState);
    UpdateKeyState('S', keyboardState);
    UpdateKeyState('T', keyboardState);
    UpdateKeyState('U', keyboardState);
    UpdateKeyState('V', keyboardState);
    UpdateKeyState('W', keyboardState);
    UpdateKeyState('X', keyboardState);
    UpdateKeyState('Y', keyboardState);
    UpdateKeyState('Z', keyboardState);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND window, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    LRESULT result = 0l;

    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        default:
            result = DefWindowProc(window, message, wParam, lParam);
            break;
    }

    return result;
}

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE instance, HINSTANCE, LPWSTR commandLine, int showCommand)
{
    WCHAR className[] = L"KeyboardStateApplication";

    WNDCLASSEX windowClass = { };
    windowClass.cbSize = sizeof(windowClass);
    windowClass.hInstance = instance;
    windowClass.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;
    windowClass.lpszClassName = className;

    int exitCode = 0;

    if (RegisterClassEx(&windowClass))
    {
        HWND window = CreateWindowEx(0ul, className, nullptr, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, nullptr, nullptr, instance, nullptr);

        ShowWindow(window, showCommand);
        UpdateWindow(window);

        MSG message = { };
        bool exit = false;

        wstring keyboardState;

        while (true)
        {
            while (PeekMessage(&message, nullptr, 0u, 0u, PM_NOREMOVE))
            {
                if (GetMessage(&message, nullptr, 0u, 0u))
                {
                    DispatchMessage(&message);
                }
                else
                {
                    exit = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (exit)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                Update(keyboardState);
                Render(window, keyboardState);
            }
        }

        exitCode = message.wParam;
    }

    return exitCode;
}
```

Comment: prob a limitation of the actual keyboard which typically can only register a small number of keys being down at once

Comment: I've thought of that too, but why it's so undetermined? Sometimes I get correct state of 3 keys and sometimes of 8 or even more.

Comment: See for example [Keyboard Ghosting Explained](https://www.microsoft.com/appliedsciences/antighostingexplained.mspx).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_%28key%29

Answer (score 0):

You should use [GetKeyboardState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646299(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the current status of all the virtual keys.

Comment: I've tried using it, as I mentioned in the OP. The problem is in hardware.

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(key)#Key_jamming_and_ghosting
most keyboards can't read more than 3 keys pressed simultaneously